# Rename tag ibm-q-experience to ibm-quantum-experience

Tags: support, tags, tagging

The tag `ibm-q-experience` has been used to associate questions with IBM's quantum processors which are accessible online, as well as usage of these devices through the IBM Q Experience site. As of January 8th, the site has been renamed to the IBM Quantum Experience, and is being referred to as such. I suggest renaming the tag to `ibm-quantum-experience` to reflect this change.

Comment: we can simply add a synonym or redirect so that both tags will work

Comment: Although renaming would be preferable, if this is the simpler option then I think it would work fine. Would it be possible to have ibm-q-experience be the synonym and have ibm-quantum-experience become the main tag though?

Comment: One thing that makes me slightly hesitant is that the IBM website links to the current tag. I think making it a synonym should sort this out though

Comment: I assume the link you are talking about is located here: https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/support, right? If, in the future, this link was edited to point to a ibm-quantum-experience tag that was set up as a synonym for ibm-q-experience, everything would still work similarly correct?

Comment: Is there something else I would need to do to have this synonym for the ibm-q-experience tag created? Would I need to submit/fill out something at a different part of the site? Or is this question sufficient?